# Snowflake as an archive store?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

(Looking for a confirmation of the following for a Snowflake User)

---

User:

> I wanted to find out if archival use case will be a right fit for Snowflake. My data lake/DW is on Snowflake but I have a requirement to archive data that is n years old. Should I use S3 or Glacier instead. My understanding is that if I archive on s3/glacier retrieval will be complex.

Response:

> I would suggest to compare the storage cost for Snowflake storage vs AWS Glacier/S3.
>
> In case if you plan to query data you have following options:
>
> a. AWS Glacier Select (has limitation)
>
> b. Copy data from Glacier to S3 and then query via Athena or Snowflake
>
> c. Snowflake query for S3 storage.
>
> d. If the data is in Snowflake then Snowflake sql.
>
> Overall Snowflake separate table storage options looks better.

---

Can we get a confirmation of the above from the SO Community?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my opinion, keeping the data in Snowflake is no longer a luxury, and for customer running on AWS, the underlying storage is S3 (and compressed by default by Snowflake). You can still perform an "archival" in the sense of moving the older data to another table/schema, that way you can keep the base table a certain size (and arguably, a certain performance, but even that,  in Snowflake this might be a moot point too).

One thing to note is that AWS Glacier is really cheap, until the point you need to retrieve data from it.

Answer (score 1):

another option is to archive [back into S3 from snowflake](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/sql/copy-into-location.html) and use an external table against the archived data. This will be slower for retrieval and I dont think it would be any cheaper than using Snowflake. I think in terms of just pure storage costs, glacier will be cheapest but if you need to ever query the data its not optimal.

Answer (score 1):

As noted in a previous comment, you can move the data to a separate database as an archive, and limit access to it as necessary. And Glacier is not much of an option if you ever plan to query it, as that is where you pay the costs.

One other thing to consider is that the big difference in simply storing data in S3 versus Snowflake, is in the cost to load/parse the data. Loading/parsing takes a lot of compute power, probably even worse so if you use JSON data instead of CSV. In your case if you already have the data in Snowflake, exporting back out to S3 seems like a waste.